# Autopopulate Cell Based on Adjacent Cell Vlue

Tags: worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet that has a drop down list in Column B, I want to auto-populate Column C with the dollar amounts based on what is in Column B.  So if Column B has "Chicken" I want it to fill Column C with the price "$9.99.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a reference table in another worksheet (eg. Sheet2) with 2 columns **Item** and **Price**.

```
Col A   Col B
Item    Price
Chicken $9.99 
Beef    $12.00 
Pork    $8.99
```

Then in column C in Sheet1, put this code in cell C2 and drag down to apply the formula to all rows in Column C. Please note that your range `Sheet2!$A$1:$B$4` depends on how extensive is your item & price list, more or less. Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$4,2,FALSE)
```